# Изменить цвет части текста в TextView

Tags: android

Нужно сделать первые буквы красными, можно через ресурсы, можно в коде!
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

С помощью [span](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html).

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

final SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder("Text");
final ForegroundColorSpan style = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
text.setSpan(style, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(text);
```

Comment: Получается сделать только одну букву, а если мне нужно с 0 по 1 и с 20 по 21 допустим? 
И как сделать зачеркнутый текст, жирный, подстрочный?

Comment: C 0 по 1 и с 3 по 5 зачеркнутый
`final SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder("Texttext");
        final ForegroundColorSpan style = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
        final ForegroundColorSpan style2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
        text.setSpan(style, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(style2, 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        textView.setText(text);`

Comment: Жирный
`textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);`